# Regular conditional probability living on sections

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $\bar X$ be standard Borel spaces, let $A\subseteq X\times \bar X$ be an analytic subset of the product space and let $P$ be a probability measure such that $P(A) = 1$. Does there exists a regular conditional probability $p:X\times \mathcal B(\bar X) \to [0,1]$ such that $p(x,A_x) = 1$ for all $x\in X$? Here
$$
A_x := \{\bar x\in \bar X:(x,\bar x)\in A\}
$$
is an $x$-section of $A$ and $\mathcal B(\bar X)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. To avoid trivial counterexamples, here we assume that $A_x \neq\emptyset$ for each $x\in X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if the kernel should be Borel measurable. The main result in [Non-Existence of Everywhere Proper Conditional Distributions](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177704259) by Blackwell and Ryll-Nardzewski implies that this is never the case if $A$ is the graph of a Borel measurable function that doesn't have a Borel set as range.

Comment: But in this case the kernel still can be universally measurable, I guess, right?

Comment: I'm not sure. There is an exceptional null set where the kernel is not supported on the sections and I see in general no reason why one can change the kernel there unless one uses the completion of one factor.

Comment: $A$ contains a graph of an analyticically measurable map, which we can use as a modification of the kernel on a null set.

Comment: @Ilya What is an analytically measurable map. If it is a map such that Borel sets have analytic preimage, it is the same thing as a Borel measurable map, since the preimage of a Borel set would be both analytic and coanalytic and hence Borel. Why would the modification on a null set be still measurable?

Comment: measurable w.r.t. the minimal $\sigma$-algebra that contains analytic sets (it's Jankov-von Neumann). The modification will be analytically measurable as well

Comment: @Ilya I see. In that case, you can indeed get a universally measurable kernel.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer soon, so far I've accepted yours - would you please indicate that in the OP it was unclear that I meant only Borel kernels, and that your answer provides a link to a counterexample?